# Convert existing String date into Y/m/d - Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have an existing Date which I want to convert to it as (Y/m/d). My Date call is already as `{$module_data.DATE}`. How can I convert it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{$module_data.DATE|date_format:"%Y/%m/%d"}
```